# gnu ld/gdb: separate debug files. How to produce the debug file when there's too much debug info to link?

Tags: debugging, gdb, binutils

There's now `gdb` and `binutils` support for separating debug info from the binaries to be debugged.  Docs describing this can be found in:

- [gdb: separate debug files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)
- [objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink, --only-keep-debug](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/binutils/objcopy.html#objcopy)
- [ld --build-id](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

After a bit of experimenting, I'm able to get `gdb` (7.6) to find the debug info using either the build-id and debug-link methods.  Here's two `gdb` fragments that show the debugger finding the debug info in the non-standard locations, using the build-id and debug-link methods respectively:

```
(gdb)  set debug-file-directory .
(gdb) file uWithBuildId
Reading symbols from /home/peeterj/build-id/uWithBuildId...Reading symbols from /home/peeterj/build-id/.build-id/2d/41caac1bcbeb65255abc3f35624cf9ed37791a.debug...done.


Reading symbols from /home/peeterj/build-id/uWithDebugLink...Reading symbols from /home/peeterj/build-id/uWithDebugLink.debug...done.
```

To create the debug info files I've used `objcopy` and `strip`.  I've included details of such commands below for reference.

However, the reason I'm looking at this at all is with the hope of being able to build *all* of our product code with `-g`.  Currently this breaks the debugger if we try since our shared-lib is too big with relocation truncated to fit messages like:

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o:(.debug_aranges+0x6):     relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.debug_info'
```

(and subsequent link failure)

Does anybody know of a way to do one of:

1. Generate a standalone file containing all the debug info from the sources that contribute to the binary (i.e all the .o's and .a's that end up in the `ld` command that generates the binary).
2. Or, instruct `ld` to link without including this debug info in the binary itself, and generate a standalone debug file that can be identified with a build-id or debug-link?  I don't see anything in the docs for a single pass method to do this with `ld`, but the `ld` docs are big and perhaps I missed it.
3. Some way to deal with the truncation error above (such a method would allow either the build-id or debug-link methods to work).

### sample commands to generate separate debug files for an executable

Here's a sample command line sequence using both the `--build-id` and `--add-gnu-debuglink` methods:

```
g++ -g   -c -o u.o u.cpp
g++ -o uWithBuildId -Wl,--build-id u.o
g++ -o uWithDebugLink u.o
copyDebugAndStrip uWithBuildId
objcopy --only-keep-debug uWithDebugLink uWithDebugLink.debug
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=uWithDebugLink.debug uWithDebugLink
strip -g uWithDebugLink
```

where copyDebugAndStrip is the following perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $binary = $ARGV[0] ;
my @p = `objdump --section .note.gnu.build-id -s $binary | tail -2` ;
foreach (@p)
{
   chomp ;
   s/^ *[\da-f]+ *// ;
   s/  .*// ;
   s/ //g ;
}

my $buildid = "$p[0]$p[1]" ;
$buildid =~ /^(..)(.*)/ ;

my ($d, $r) = ($1, $2) ;

print "build-id for '$binary': $buildid\n" ;

my $cmd =
"mkdir -p .build-id/$d
rm -f .build-id/$d/$r.debug
objcopy --only-keep-debug $binary .build-id/$d/$r.debug
strip -g $binary
" ;

print $cmd ;
system $cmd ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initially it appeared that the `binutils` gold linker was capable of building large -g shared libs, providing a solution for (3) above, however, it turns out that is because of a lack of error checking.

On the other hand it looks like work on (1) and (2) is in available if a bleeding edge toolchain is used, part of the fission dwarf/binutils/gcc work described here:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-10/msg00326.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DebugFission

This fission work was mentioned in discussion of a bugzilla report on this relocation truncation error:

http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15444

An example of the use of this split debug files is:

```
g++ -gsplit-dwarf -gdwarf-4   -c -o main.o main.cpp
gcc -gsplit-dwarf -gdwarf-4   -c -o d1/t1.o d1/t1.c
g++ -gsplit-dwarf -gdwarf-4   -c -o d2/t2.o d2/t2.cpp
gcc -Wl,--index-gdb main.o d1/t1.o d2/t2.o   -o main
```

where `gcc`/`g++` are version 4.8, the `binutils` trunk (`cvs -z 9 -d :pserver:anoncvs@sourceware.org:/cvs/src co binutils`) has been used configured with `--enable-gold=default`, and finally using gdb version 7.6 which can read the split debug info.

Joining gcc in the party, the intel (version 16) compiler supports -gsplit-dwarf.  The intel compiler documents that binutils-2.24+,gdb-7.6.1+ are required.  The clang compiler codebase has some split dwarf support, but I don't know what state that support is in.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue  with linker when compiling with g++ (v6.3.0) + gold linker (v2.27) + “-g” parameter.

staticlib.a(sharedlib.o):(.debug_loc+0x1d38): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.debug_info'
staticlib.a(sharedlib.o):(.debug_loc+0x6c8c): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [exec_file] Error 1
287.760u 35.837s 7:30.37 71.8%  0+0k 17217048+14932696io 0pf+0w

Adding the parameter "-fdebug-types-section" fixed this issue.

More details at: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html